# Where is the Syntax Error in this MS Access Nested IIF with Parameters Query?

Tags: ms-access, parameters, sum, iif, inventory-management

I am trying to create a query in Access that sums the number of Projects Under Consideration and Development as a Month End Inventory. There are three fields I need to get that number dtCreate, dtLegalEnd, and dtFinalClosed, but I also need the code to be dynamic so that it can pull that same sum for a give month, months and years after it has passed. So I tried to do it has a nested IIF parameter query with the following syntax:

**SELECT sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtCreate]>[Enter Date End of Month],0,sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtLegalEnd]>[Enter Date End of Month] or is null,0,Sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtFinalClosed]>[Enter Date End of Month] or is null,0,1))))))
FROM tblProjectsA;**

Where is my syntax error(s)?  Is there a better way to achieve the same result or have the results for each mm/yyyy query?

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: You must specify which parameter(s) or field(s) to check for `Is Null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

SELECT sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtCreate]>[Enter Date End of Month],0,sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtLegalEnd]>[Enter Date End of Month]
or **[tblProjectsA].[dtLegalEnd] is null**,0,Sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtFinalClosed]>[Enter Date End of Month] or **[tblProjectsA].[dtFinalClosed] is null**,0,1)))))) FROM tblProjectsA;

As for having results for each mm/yyyy, you should use GROUP BY clause, like

```
SELECT Month([your date]) AS Month, Year([your date]) AS Year, ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY Month([your date]), Year([your date])
```

Comment: Thanks your for response.  I gave it a try and access spit back the error message that there can't be an aggregate in the WHERE clause
sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtLegalEnd]>[Enter Date End of Month] or [tblProjectsA].[dtLegalEnd] is null,0,Sum(IIF([tblProjectsA].[dtFinalClosed]>[Enter Date End of Month] or [tblProjectsA].[dtFinalClosed] is null,0,1)))))).  Which doesn't make a ton of sense given that it's the SELECT clause.

Comment: That's because you should use HAVING instead WHERE for aggregates. WHERE is for raw fields or expressions containing raw fields (or constants) from the tables involved, restraining the data to summarize. So you use WHERE clause before HAVING for stretching the data to summarize and HAVING for obtaining only the results wanted after summarize

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you are summing a sum.  Sum is an sql function that if Sum(column) where column has 5 rows that all = 1, then Sum will return 5.  When you try to call sum inside sum Access doesn't officially know what column to pass to the inner sum to get a value to put in the outer sum.  So Access throws an error,  you can tell access to calculate the inner sum first by wrapping it in a subquery.
But I find subqueries are harder to understand and don't have good Access designer support.  So instead I use calculated fields which I find more intuitive and declaritive.

```
ProjectUnderConsideration: IIf(([dtCreate]<[MonthEnd]) And ([dtFinalClosed]<[MonthEnd]) And (([dtLegalEnd]<[MonthEnd]) Or IsNull([dtLegalEnd])),1,0)
```

I don't understand the construct of ProjectUnderConsideration.  Adjust this explanation to your actual case.  I assumed a project is under consideration if dtCreate, dtLegalEnd, and dtFinalClosed are all < MonthEnd.  and for demonstration I assumed dtLegalEnd could be null.

You can use the Designer in Access to help you write and test your sql:

[image]

```
'sql
PARAMETERS MonthEnd DateTime;
SELECT tblProjectsA.dtCreate, tblProjectsA.dtLegalEnd, tblProjectsA.dtFinalClosed, IIf(([dtCreate]<[MonthEnd]) And ([dtFinalClosed]<[MonthEnd]) And (([dtLegalEnd]<[MonthEnd]) Or IsNull([dtLegalEnd])),1,0) AS ProjectUnderConsideration
FROM tblProjectsA;
```

[image]

Now we have a ProjectUnderConsideration Column to sum.  Change the query to a totals query:

```
PARAMETERS MonthEnd DateTime;
SELECT Sum(IIf(([dtCreate]<[MonthEnd]) And ([dtFinalClosed]<[MonthEnd]) And (([dtLegalEnd]<[MonthEnd]) Or IsNull([dtLegalEnd])),1,0)) AS ProjectUnderConsideration
FROM tblProjectsA;
```

[image]